# Formulating a regex with a single dot

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to formulate a regex for the following scenario :

The String to match : mName87.com

So, the string may consist of any number of alpha numeric characters , but can contain only a single dot anywhere in the string .

I formulated this regex : `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`, but it matches even multiple dots(.)

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you provided matches only a single character in the whole string you're trying to validate. There are a few things to take care of in your scenario

- You want to match over the whole string, so your regex must start with `^` (beginning of the string) and end with `$` (end of the string).
- Then you want to accept any number of alpha-numeric characters, this is done with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, here the `+` means one or more characters.
- Then match the point: `\.` (you must escape it here)
- Finally accept more characters again.

All together the regex would then be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . +1 for the explanation. Will accept when stack allows me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
\\w*\\.\\w*
```

You can try [here](http://fiddle.re/htzva)

Comment: matches more than one dot at rubular.com

Comment: This will also match underscores, you may use `[^\\W_]` instead of `\\w`

Comment: @The Dark Knight use a Java regex validator like http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: It will not match `...`, just `foo.bar.baz`

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

Try

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)
```

That is: [a word that ends with a dot] OR [two words and the dot in the middle] OR [a word that starts with a dot]

Comment: I gave you a Java String, replace double slashes with single ones

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$`